# query for selecting distinct names and count names in sql

Tags: sql

In my table 2 columns are there. `Name` and `Marks`. Something like this.

```
Name         Marks
----------   -----------
AAA          50
BBB          48
CCC          54
AAA          52
DDD          55
BBB          60
AAA          66
```

I need to retrieve from the table something like below

```
Name       No.of.attempts    Max Mark
-------    ----------------  ------------
AAA         3                 66
BBB         2                 60
CCC         1                 54
DDD         1                 55
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do like:

```
select name,count(name) as no_of_attempts,max(marks) 
from table_name 
group by name
```

### <kbd>[fddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e2e5/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
 select name,COUNT(name) as nameCount,MAX(markes) as marks from #abc group by name
```